# 2D planes how it 2D inspite of it has 3 coordinates?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

We know that any point in the plane can be represented as an ordered pair $(a, b)$ of real numbers, where $a$ is the x-coordinate and $b$ is the y-coordinate.For this reason, a plane is called two-dimensional.

But why the equation of plane is $ax+by+cz+d=0$ which has 3 coordinates?

Comment: $ax + by + cz + d = 0$ This is equation of plane in $3$-Dimensions 
[Check this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+of+1x%2B2y+%2B3z+-6+%3D+0)

Comment: $\{(x,2x) \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ defines a line (1-dim) but has two coordinates in its description as $y=2x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dimension is not related to the total number of variables, but rather to the number of variables you can freely choose (degrees of freedom). For instance, if you pick some values for $x$ and $y$, you cannot freely choose the value of $z$: it will be determined by the equation.

For instance, the points that belong to the plane $x+y+z = 1$ can also be described as points of the form
$$
(x,y,z) = (0,0,1) + t (1,0,-1) + s(0,1,-1), \quad t,s \in \mathbb{R}
$$

So, choosing a point in that plane, amounts to deciding on the value of $t,s$, hence dimension 2.

Comment: when we represent a point (a, b) in xy plane, then plane equation ax+by+cz+d=0 with c=0?

Comment: @Bezier The equation of the $xy$-plane is just $z=0$, so it is the other way round: $a=b=d=0$, $c \ne 0$.

Comment: if say z=constant it may be wrong?

Comment: @Bezier Not wrong, just not the $xy$-plane. The equation $z = cte$ represents a plane which is parallel to the $xy$-plane.

Comment: one thing tell why we say xy plane is 2D, here one degree of freedom?

Comment: @Bezier The points in the $xy$-plane can be written in the form
$$ (x,y,z) = t(1,0,0) + s(0,1,0)$$
So, you do have two degrees of freedom.

Comment: xy plane is 2D, but how ax+by=d is one dimensional in xy-plane?

Comment: @Bezier You need to decide what is your reference space... If you start from $\mathbb{R}^2$ and impose a condition $ax+by=d$ you can only choose freely the value of **one** variable. So, the condition $ax+by=d$, imposed over points $(x,y)$, defines a set with dimension 1. But if you start from $\mathbb{R}^3$, the same condition $ax+by=d$, now defines a set with dimension 2 because you can freely choose **two** variables ($z$ does not even appear, so you can take any $z$).

Comment: how R2 is 2 dimensional, it has one degree of freedom?

Comment: @Bezier You just need to determine the number of free variables... In $\mathbb{R}^2$ you start with two variables. If you impose one condition, only one of those two variables remains free (hence, dimension 1).

In $\mathbb{R}^3$ you start with three variables. if you impose one condition, only two variables remain free (hence, dimension 2).

Loosely speaking, each condition removers one free variable. For instance, if you started from $\mathbb{R}^4$ and imposed 3 conditions, you would expect one (=4-3) variables.

Comment: But my question is why R^2 is 2 dimensional?

Comment: @Bezier The dimension of a vector space is the minimum number of elements in a basis. $\mathbb{R}^2$ has dimension 2 because: i. The vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ generate the whole space and ii. A single vector cannot span to the whole space.

Comment: one thing tell the homogenous coordinates (x, y, 1) it has 2 degree of freedom, so it should be 2D homogenous coordinates, but many places I have seen it is said by 3D homogenous coordinates? My question is what is right?

Answer (score 2):

The concept of a "plane" is intrinsic. Planes can exist inside other objects, and whatever is happening outside of that plane, i.e. whatever is extrinsic to that plane, is not particularly relevant to the fact that the plane is a plane.

So.... What is a plane?

Well, you can go back to axiomatic geometry, i.e. the axioms of Euclid as refined in the 19th century. Pasch's axiom says that if $P$ is a plane, and if $T$ is a triangle in $P$, and if $L$ is a line in $P$, and if $L$ does not contain a vertex of $T$, and if $L$ crosses one of the side of $T$, then $L$ must also cross one of the other two sides of $P$. I'm sure you can convince yourself that this is true in
$$(*) \quad P = \{(x,y,x) \in \mathbb R^3 \mid ax + by + cz + d = 0\} \quad\text{(assuming $(a,b,c) \ne (0,0,0)$, of course)}
$$

---

For a more Cartesian point of view, it is true that the plane $P$ given by $(*)$ is a subset of the 3-dimensional Cartesian coordinate space $\mathbb R^3$. And it is true that each point of $P$ has three coordinates $(x,y,z)$. However, those three coordinates do not vary independently within $P$. What distinguishes a plane in $\mathbb R^3$ from the whole of $\mathbb R^3$ is that within $P$ one may find two coordinates which vary independently over $P$, but one cannot find three coordinates which vary independently over $P$. And this fact is true of *any* plane embedded in $\mathbb R^3$ that is given by a formula like $(*)$.

For example, if you consider the plane $P$ in $\mathbb R^3$ given by the equation
$$3x + 2y + 5z = 7
$$
then the two coordinates $x,y$ vary independently over $P$, whereas the third coordinate $z$ is **completely determined** by the values of $x$ and $y$, which one sees easily by solving to get $z = -\frac{3}{5}x - \frac{2}{5} y + \frac{7}{5}$.

Comment: one thing tell why we say xy plane is 2D, here one degree of freedom?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. 2D means (among other things) 2 degrees of freedom. A plane does not have one degree of freedom, instead it has 2 degrees of freedom.

Comment: But one can fairly ask what "2 degrees of freedom" even means. In my Cartesian explanation, 2 degrees of freedom means that the plane can be described using 2 independent coordinates. In my example those 2 independent coordinates are $x$ and $y$.

Comment: The $x,y$ plane is also 2D, because it also has 2 independent coordinates. Those 2 independent coordinates are $x$ and $y$.

Comment: how R2 is 2 dimensional, it has one degree of freedom?

Comment: $\mathbb R^2$ does not have $1$ degree of freedom. Instead it has $2$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: what does it mean --"Planes can exist inside other objects"?

Comment: To say "a plane can exist inside $\mathbb R^3$" means that "a plane can be a subset of $\mathbb R^3$". For example the solution set of the equation $3x+2y+5z=7$ is a plane that is a subset of $\mathbb R^3$. For a simpler example, the $x$,$y$ coordinate plane $\{(x,y,0) \mid x \in \mathbb R, y \in \mathbb R\}$ is a plane that is a subset of $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: one thing tell the homogenous coordinates (x, y, 1) it has 2 degree of freedom, so it should be 2D homogenous coordinates, but many places I have seen it is said by 3D homogenous coordinates? My question is what is right?